# Array of Indexed Arrays generating malformed JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm developping an database search application with php and on one page I make a request to a serverside script through Jquery Ajax (JSON) searching for registers in the database according to a certain parameter. After the search is successfull, I echo an associative array with all the entries found encoded as JSON.

With Chrome's element inspector, I can read the response, which is like this:

```
[0: False
1: "{"id":"5","nome":"Maria","sobrenome":"Joaquina","sexo":"F","rua":"","complemento":"","numero":"0","bairro":"Aeroporto\r\n","telefone":"","email":"","nacionalidade":"Peruano"}"]
```

The element indexed 1 seems to be a well formed JSON, but I cant read from it, anything such as data[1].nome returns undefined.

I would like to know what is happening to my json and how can I solve it so I can access the objects by their attributes. Below is the code that treats the JSON.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnEnviarBairro').click(function(){
    var data = $("#bairros_juizdefora").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processaBuscaId.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id : data, type: 1},
        success: function(response){
            var table = $('<table/>');
            for ( var i = 1; i < response.length; i++){
                table.append("<tr><td>"+response[i].nome+"</tr></td>");
            }
            $('#receptorBairro').append(table);

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log(xhr+" "+status+" "+error);
        }
    }).done(function(){

    });
});});
```

Kind of controller file:

```
function buscaBairro($id, $connection) {
   $dao = new estrangeiroDao ( $connection );
   return $dao->selectbyBairroId ( $id );
};
echo json_encode (buscaBairro($selectId, $connection));
```

DAO for searching:

```
function selectbyBairroId($id) {
    $sql = 'select * from dados_estrangeiro, nacionalidade, bairros_juizdefora where bairroid = '.$id.' and idnac=idnacionalidade and idbairros_juizdefora = '.$id;
    $arres = array ();
    $result = $this->con->query ( $sql );
    while ( $obj = $result->fetch_object () ) {
        $estrangeiro = $this->objectToEstrangeiro ( $obj );
        array_push ( $arres, json_encode($estrangeiro->returnAsAssoc()) );
    }
    return $arres;

}
}
```

ObjectToEstrangeiro Method (used above):

```
function objectToEstrangeiro($obj) {
    $est = new estrangeiros ( $obj->idestrangeiro, $obj->pnome, $obj->snome, $obj->sexo, $obj->rua, $obj->complemento, $obj->numero, utf8_encode ( $obj->nomebairros_juizdefora ), $obj->telefone, $obj->email, utf8_encode ( $obj->nomenacionalidade ) );
    return $est;
}
```

"Bean" (I know it is java stuff, but I learnd and tryed to implement in PHP) for Estrangeiro table:

```
class estrangeiros {
[...]
[... Attributes and Getters and Setters (I dont know if they are usfull in PHP...]
[...]
    public function returnAsAssoc(){
        $arres= array("id"=>$this->getId(), "nome" => $this->getNome(), "sobrenome"=>$this->getSobrenome(), "sexo"=>$this->getSexo(),
                "rua"=>$this->getRua(), "complemento"=>$this->getComplemento(), "numero"=>$this->getNumero(), "bairro"=>$this->getBairro(),
                "telefone" =>$this->getTelefone(), "email"=> $this->getEmail(), "nacionalidade"=>$this->getNacionalidade()
        );

        return $arres;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As from the comments, I can see the response is malformed JSON, but now I'm trying to find out why.

Here are some things I found:

I pass an array of json encoded associative arrays to the controller, where it is again json encoded and echoed.
If remove any of the json encodings, I get no response in Jquery.

Also, I cannot encode an array of objects, right (at least not with private attributes)? So I have to turn the objects I'm fetching into associative arrays and then store them in another array so I can access their values.

Comment: Using `jsonlint.org` your JSON appears to be `Badly Formed` But if you remove the `[0: False1: "` from the front and `"]` from the end It does validate

Comment: Any hints why? It seems to be well formed after the index.... If it is malformed, how is it being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling, I found the error. It was on the utf-8 enconding of the data stored in the DB. After fixing that, no more JSON errors.

Always remember to use UTF-8 on your JSON!

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be your reason.

You are converting each data item from your data collection function `selectbyBairroId` to JSON and then returning that array and again converting it to JSON.

You should only do it once, build your data in a completely PHP data structure and then, just before sending it back to whereever, you convert it all to JSON in one go.

```
function selectbyBairroId($id) {
    $sql = 'select * from dados_estrangeiro, 
                          nacionalidade, 
                          bairros_juizdefora 
            where bairroid = '.$id.' 
              and idnac=idnacionalidade 
              and idbairros_juizdefora = '.$id;

    $arres = array ();

    $result = $this->con->query ( $sql );

    while ( $obj = $result->fetch_object () ) {
        $estrangeiro = $this->objectToEstrangeiro ( $obj );

        //array_push ($arres, json_encode($estrangeiro->returnAsAssoc()));

        $arres[] = $estrangeiro->returnAsAssoc();
    }
    return $arres;
}


function buscaBairro($id, $connection) {
    $dao = new estrangeiroDao ( $connection );
    return $dao->selectbyBairroId ( $id );
};

echo json_encode (buscaBairro($selectId, $connection));
```

**After this comment in your question:**

*Also, I cannot encode an array of objects, right (at least not with private attributes)? So I have to turn the objects I'm fetching into associative arrays and then store them in another array so I can access their values.*

Yes you can encode an array of objects. The objects returned by `->fetch_object()` are housed in an object defined by `stdClass()` and therefore all the properties are public.

So try this simplified `selectbyBairroId` function

```
function selectbyBairroId($id) {
    $sql = 'select * from dados_estrangeiro, 
                          nacionalidade, 
                          bairros_juizdefora 
            where bairroid = '.$id.' 
              and idnac=idnacionalidade 
              and idbairros_juizdefora = '.$id;

    $arres = array ();

    $result = $this->con->query ( $sql );

    while ( $obj = $result->fetch_object () ) {
         $arres[] = $obj;
    }
    return $arres;
}
```

and you should have an array of object all with the properties of the result set defined by your query.

Comment: Nope =/ It gives me "[object Object] parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: I dont know what this line is supposed to be doing `$estrangeiro = $this->objectToEstrangeiro ( $obj );`

Comment: Oh, right. I'll add to the body. But in simple terms, it takes a Mysqli fetched object and turns into an Estrangeiro object.

Comment: Yeah, I could have done that - it is much simpler. But I'm still sticking to my own object in order to to help with generalization.

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid JSON, must be:

```
[0: "False", 1: "{"id":"5","nome":"Maria","sobrenome":"Joaquina","sexo":"F","rua":"","complemento":"","numero":"0","bairro":"Aeroporto\r\n","telefone":"","email":"","nacionalidade":"Peruano"}"]
```

Comment: Do you know why this "False" is appearning there? It was not my intention to add it in there.